# I´m searching for cracklib2-dev to use in progress of connecting my mac to the ubuntu server

Tags: glibc

Tried for many hours to install cracklib2-dev. How can i do this in terminal?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what have you done to try to install it ?

Comment: You may need to use this ppa, depending on your version of Ubuntu - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cracklib2

Comment: I have i386 I found the page and downloaded the package but stuck with the installation on my server.